# How do I make a div stretch outside of the wrapper while keeping its text inside the wrapper?

Tags: css

I want to make the green box extend outside of the wrapper while keeping the white phone number inside the wrapper. My best attempt at this was to make a separate green box outside the wrapper, but then sizing it is an issue, and I just want to figure out a cleaner way of doing it. It's not showing up properly on this JSfiddle for some reason.

https://jsfiddle.net/m9vqwkbf/

```
<li id="phone-green-box">
    <span class="phone-icon"></span>
    <a>(434)444-1060</a>
</li>
```

Also I had to put it in an li tag because I couldn't get it to float where I wanted as an h2. If someone can help me make this thing an h2 that stretches out like it's supposed to, that would be awesome. ^_^ Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What all do you want to be green? Can you clarify your question a little bit?

Comment: Some more details would definitely help.  There's probably a better way to get what you want without having the contents spill out of their container.  The way you describe it now you would have to absolute position the text and then let the box be whatever size you need.

Comment: Having contents spill out of a container is never a good approach when it comes to web.  That's what the container is for, to contain things.

Comment: I want it to be the same as the blue box on this page: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/real-homes-wordpress-real-estate-theme/full_screen_preview/5373914

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/m9vqwkbf/1/